# Add data from all files in a directory to SPLUNK

Tags: splunk

I want to monitor all my files data from a particular directory in splunk .

Can you tell me the detailed steps for doing so ..

Comment: You would need to send the data/logs using the Splunk Light Forwarder to the Splunk instance, and after that you can monitor the data

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create a monitor input, there is extensive documentation on [docs.splunk.com](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Monitorfilesanddirectories)

Comment: Thank you ..My use case : I want my splunk to index  all merged contents of all files inside a monitoring folder  . and also if I add some more files ..those contents are also be appended to the splunk index

Comment: @SandeepDas do you need any further help? If not, can you accept my answer?

Comment: I need further help.--I want my splunk to index all merged contents of all files inside a monitoring folder . and also if I add some more files ..those contents are also be appended to the splunk index

Comment: @SandeepDas I'm not sure I understand your question, have you asked on answers.splunk.com? There may even be a similar question/answer there

Comment: Explaining it in detail : I have a folder called "SplunkAnalysis" .In that folder i put csv files weekly .Eg: week1.csv,week2.csv,week3.csv .......All csv's have same structure . Now my requirement is : In stead of merging all csv files or explicitly adding into splunk I want to monitor all data inside "splunkAnalysis" folder in splunk .Can I do that

Comment: @SandeepDas absolutely, when you create the monitor input via the UI, select the option that's something like "Continuously index data from a file or directory this Splunk instance can access" and that will do exactly what you want